# Perform Simple Calculations Using Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way to perform simple calculations on data by using the security rules?

For example,

`data.val() = data.val() + newData.val()`

The intentions are to take the current value `data.val()` stored at this location and increment that value with the new value `newData.val()`.

Basically, I need to change data during a `write`.

Comment: Security rules only enforce read/write permissions and data validity. They can't change data.

Comment: I figured that was the case. I wonder if Firebase plans to add this functionality.

Comment: @AnidMonsur can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[Security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/index.html) only enforce read/write permissions and data validity. They cannot modify data.